# How do i get the full strings with a RegEx search in python that only captures part of the word?

Tags: python, regex, string, text, text-mining

My assignment is to search through a document, and grab the words that contain ch, cH,Ch, CH, sh, sH, Sh, and SH. What is the most effective way to grab the whole word? right now using re.findall() i get the correct count of words and location, but am only able to print the ch or sh, not the whole word that contained the letters.
 Here is my code!

```
import re

#f = open("dreamMLK.txt",'r')

with open("dreamMLK.txt",'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    count = 1
    while line:
        x = re.findall("ch|sh",line)
        if(len(x) > 0):
            print(x)
            print(str(count) +": "+line)
        line = fp.readline()
        count += 1
```

and here is the output:

```
['sh']
3: Five score years ago, a great American, in whose symbolic shadow we stand today, signed the Emancipation Proclamation. This momentous decree came as a great beacon light of hope to millions of Negro slaves [Audience:] (Yeah) who had been seared in the flames of withering injustice. It came as a joyous daybreak to end the long night of their captivity. (Hmm)

['ch', 'sh', 'sh']
5: But one hundred years later (All right), the Negro still is not free. (My Lord, Yeah) One hundred years later, the life of the Negro is still sadly crippled by the manacles of segregation and the chains of discrimination. (Hmm) One hundred years later (All right), the Negro lives on a lonely island of poverty in the midst of a vast ocean of material prosperity. One hundred years later (My Lord) [applause], the Negro is still languished in the corners of American society and finds himself in exile in his own land. (Yes, yes) And so we’ve come here today to dramatize a shameful condition.
```

I want line 3 to print value Shadow, not 'sh'. And line 5 to print Chains, Languished, and Shameful. Here is the assignment verbatim, if interested:

**Open a file and using a while loop to read in each line, use regular expressions (re.search()) to find those lines that contain any lower/upper case version of the strings "ch" or sh", i.e.  {ch Ch cH CH sh sH Sh SH}.  NOTE - do not enumerate all 8 possibilities in the regular expression, rather, your regular expression should be 7 characters long including the [ ] charachters.  For each sentenct that contains a "ch" or "sh" (or Ch or CH or cH etc) print out: a) the line number and the sentance; and b) the list of the words in that sentence contaiing some version of "sh" or "ch".**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following regex pattern, in case insensitive mode:

```
\b\S*[cs]h\S*\b
```

This will match all words containing `ch` or `sh`.  Here is a sample script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
inp = """3: Five score years ago, a great American, in whose symbolic shadow we stand today, signed the Emancipation Proclamation. This momentous decree came as a great beacon light of hope to millions of Negro slaves [Audience:] (Yeah) who had been seared in the flames of withering injustice. It came as a joyous daybreak to end the long night of their captivity.
5: But one hundred years later (All right), the Negro still is not free. (My Lord, Yeah) One hundred years later, the life of the Negro is still sadly crippled by the manacles of segregation and the chains of discrimination. (Hmm) One hundred years later (All right), the Negro lives on a lonely island of poverty in the midst of a vast ocean of material prosperity. One hundred years later (My Lord) [applause], the Negro is still languished in the corners of American society and finds himself in exile in his own land. (Yes, yes) And so we’ve come here today to dramatize a shameful condition."""

matches = re.findall(r'\b\S*[cs]h\S*\b', inp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['shadow', 'chains', 'languished', 'shameful']
```